# ¿Cómo usar varios botones con JavaScript y HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<center>
        <button name="monedaD">DOLAR</button>
        <button name="monedaE">EURO</button>
        <button name="monedaC">COLON</button>
</center>
```

Intenté asignarles un nombre, pero no funcionó a la hora de llamarlos en JavaScript.

```
var d = document.querySelector("monedaD")
d.onclick =alert("funciona");

var d = document.querySelector("monedaE")
d.onclick =alert("funciona");

var d = document.querySelector("monedaC")
d.onclick =alert("funciona");
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. El título y el cuerpo de la publicación son cosas diferentes, los títulos deben ser descriptivos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero es que no debes repetir las variables, a tus 3 variables les llamaste "d"

La "mejor" forma de buscar un elemento en javascript es por medio de su id y usando getElementById (fíjate que cambié name por id)

```
  <button id="monedaD">DOLAR</button>

  var d = document.getElementById("monedaD");
```

Luego la otra manera es usando querySelector, pero esta función tiene un truco, funciona muy parecido a los selectores de CSS, donde:

- Un id empieza con #
- Una clase empieza con un punto .
- Un tag no tiene prefijo
- Hay muchas más reglas, y se pueden combinar

Te pongo unos ejemplo:

Por Id:

```
    <button id="monedaD">DOLAR</button>
    var d = document.querySelector("#monedaD");
```

Por Clase

```
   <button class="monedaD">DOLAR</button>
   var d = document.querySelector(".monedaD");
```

Por Tag

```
   <button>DOLAR</button>
   var d = document.querySelector("button");
```

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector` funciona sobre selectores CSS. Como en tu ejemplo los botones no tienen id, y tampoco tienen una clase CSS. puedes usar el siguiente selector

```javascript
const d = document.querySelector("button[name='monedaD']")
d.onclick = () => alert("funciona");
```

Y así con los otros botones.

Si notaste, he cambiado la linea del `onclick`, asignando una "función flecha" en lugar de asignarle el `alert` directamente, así funcionaria como se espera.

Answer (score 0):

addEventListener() Registra un evento a un objeto en específico.

```js
document.querySelector('button[name="monedaD"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('monedaD')
})

document.querySelector('button[name="monedaE"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('monedaE')
})

document.querySelector('button[name="monedaC"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('monedaC')
})
```